# How to obtain total available disk space in Posix systems?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, unix, posix

I'm writing a cross-platform application, and I need the total available disk space. For posix systems (Linux and Macos) I'm using statvfs. I created this C++ method:

```
long OSSpecificPosix::getFreeDiskSpace(const char* absoluteFilePath) {
   struct statvfs buf;

   if (!statvfs(absoluteFilePath, &buf)) {
      unsigned long blksize, blocks, freeblks, disk_size, used, free;
      blksize = buf.f_bsize;
      blocks = buf.f_blocks;
      freeblks = buf.f_bfree;

      disk_size = blocks*blksize;
      free = freeblks*blksize;
      used = disk_size - free;

      return free;
   }
   else {
      return -1;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting quite strange values I can't understand. For instance:
f_blocks = 73242188
f_bsize = 1048576
f_bfree = 50393643
...

Are those values in bits, bytes or anything else? I read here on stackoverflow those should be bytes, but then I would get the total number of bytes free is:
f_bsize*f_bfree = 1048576*50393643
but this means 49212.542GB... too much...

Am I doing something wrong with the code or anything else?
Thanks!

Comment: What filesystem are you using that has a block size of 1048576?

Comment: This is a Mac OS Extended (Case-Sensitive, Journaled). Right now I'm working on mac, but, as far as I can understand, this is supposed to work.

Comment: Aside from the weirdness with your block size and your alleged 70TB drive - beware that a `long` on 32-bit OSX is only 32 bits. Even once you have the right numbers, that's probably big enough for your number of *blocks*, but not big enough for your number of *bytes*. Drives as big as 4GB are readily available from specialist suppliers ;-)

Comment: Aside from the mistake on the returned type, no reason why I get strange values in the structure? Any other way to get those values? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, now that I take a closer look at it, check whether `f_bsize` and `f_frsize` are equal. I bet they aren't. The numbers of blocks and blocks free refer to `f_frsize`, not `f_bsize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the last two answers are correct and useful. However I solved by simply replacing the function *statvfs* with the function *statfs*. The block size is then 4096 as expected and everything seems to be correct.
Thanks!

Comment: I can't see where `statfs` is deprecated on OS X. Also `statfs` produces the correct values.

Comment: I also can't see that: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html.

Comment: Apple documentation says this at the end of statvfs doc: The statvfs() and fstatvfs() functions conform to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'').  As standardized, portable applications cannot depend on these functions returning any valid information at all.  This implementation attempts to provide as much useful information as is provided by the underlying file system, subject to the limitations of the specified data types.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know OSX well enough to predict this is definitely the answer, but `f_blocks` and `f_bfree` actually refer to "fundamental blocks", or "fragments" (which are of size `buf.f_frsize` bytes), not the "filesystem block size" (which is `buf.f_bsize` bytes):

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html

`f_bsize` is just a hint what the preferred size is for I/O operations, it's not necessarily anything to do with how the filesystem is divided.

Answer (score 3):

The following lines:

```
disk_size = blocks*blksize;
free = freeblks*blksize;
```

Will cause overflow when having HUGE HDs.

I was getting strange results too until I figured out my HD is 455GiB , please consider casting blocks,blksize and freeblks vars to unsigned long long before doing the multiplication .

Something like this:

```
unsigned long long disk_size = (unsigned long long) (blocks) * (unsigned long long) (blksize)
```

I've seen lots of questions like this but nobody noticed this on the answers.

Comment: Good catch! I too saw the weird numbers being (unsigned long long)

Answer (score 1):

```
uint64_t userAvailableFreeSpace()
{
    struct statvfs stat;
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    if ( NULL != pw && 0 == statvfs(pw->pw_dir, &stat) )
    {
        uint64_t freeBytes = (uint64_t)stat.f_bavail * stat.f_frsize;
        return freeBytes;
    }
    return 0ULL;
}
```